# MySQL Inner Join, selecting from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm really struggling to get my head around this. I am trying to run a SELECT query from multiple tables.

This is what I have so far that doesn't work;

```
SELECT jira_issues.*, session_set.* FROM jira_issues, session_set
INNER JOIN reports on jira_issues.report_id = reports.id 
    WHERE jira_issues.report_id = 648
```

I have other tables (session_set, report_device) which has a ReportID and report_id column respectively.

I have a report table which has a Primary Key `id`. In the other tables the report.id key is linked with foreign keys.

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is this:
I have an entry in the reports table with an id of 648. In the other tables (jira_issues, report_device, session_set), I also have entries which has a foreign key linked to the report id in the report table.

I want to run one SELECT Query to query the tables (jira_issues, report_device and session_set) and get all the data from them based on the report.id.

Thanks!

Comment: As a best practice: Use one type of join - the ANSI style (i.e.,`JOIN foo ON ..`  You are using both the ANSI style and the theta style (i.e., the comma separated tables in the FROM clause).

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
SELECT * FROM jira_issues ji
    LEFT JOIN session_set ss ON ji.report_id = ss.ReportID
    LEFT JOIN report_device rd ON rd.report_id = ji.report_id
WHERE ji.report_id = 648;
```

Comment: Ah super! What if I wanted to limit the columns from each of the tables? For example, I only want issue_id and issue_key from the jira_issues table and the device_name from the report_device table. Thanks!

Comment: Just specify the column name in the SELECT rather than using SELECT *. For exaple SELECT ji.issue_id, ji.issue_key .

Comment: Thanks, one more thing! What if I wanted to select the data from the Reports table too?

Comment: You can LEFT JOIN on another table easily enough

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *`, just use `SELECT ji.field1, rd.field2` to select `field1` from table `jira_issues` and `field2` from table `report_device`.

Answer (score 0):

Just say "no" to commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT ji.*, session_set.*
FROM jira_issues ji inner join
     reports r
     on ji.report_id = r.id  inner join
     session_set ss
     on ss.ReportId = r.report_id
WHERE ji.report_id = 648;
```

If some of the tables might have no corresponding rows, you might want `left outer join` instead of `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this out. You may get syntax error.

SELECT a.*, b.* FROM jira_issues a, session_set b, reports c
Where a.report_id = c.id and b.report_id = c.id AND a.report_id = 648